# Study the behaviour of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I'm trying to study the behaviour of the following differential equation:
$$
x''(t)=\frac{n-2}{x(t)}(1+x'(t)^2),
$$
where $n$ is a natural number $(n\geq 3)$ and we are assuming that $t>0$ and $x(t)>0$ $\forall t\in (t_0,\infty)$. Specifically I want to know if a the solution to the previous differential equation (with initial conditions $x(t_0)=a>0$, $x'(t_0)=b>0$) can be extended to $(t_0,\infty)$ or it explotes in finite time.

Numerically, I have seen  that for $n=3$ the solution $x(t)$ can be extended to $(t_0,\infty)$, and for $n\geq 4$ the solution explotes in finite time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question. This is the analytical solving of the ODE.
$$x''(t)=\frac{n-2}{x(t)}(1+x'(t)^2),$$
$$\frac{2x''x'}{1+(x')^2}=2(n-2)\frac{x'}{x}$$
$$\ln|1+(x')^2|=2(n-2)\ln|x|+\text{constant}$$
$$1+(x')^2=c\:x^{2(n-2)}$$
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{c\:x^{2(n-2)}-1}}=dt$$
$$t=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c\:x^{2(n-2)}-1}}+\text{constant}$$
With condition $x(t_0)=a$ :
$$t=t_0+\int_a^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{c\:\chi^{2(n-2)}-1}}$$
With condition $x'(t_0)=b$ :
$$t=t_0+\int_a^x \frac{d\chi}{\sqrt{(b^2+1)\left(\frac{\chi}{a}\right)^{2(n-2)}-1}}$$
The explicit solution $t(x)$ involves an hypergeometric function in the general case (n>3). The case $n=3$ can be solved with elementary functions.